# Unable to convert floats to ints

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, type-conversion, int

I have a dataset about movies and there's a column that corresponds to each movies' release year. The numbers are currently all floats and I'm trying to convert them to integer.

This is the code I've written to do so:

```
if isinstance (data['Year'], float):
    for idx, i in enumerate(data['Year']):
        data['Year'][idx]= int(i)
else:
    pass
```

The code runs. However, whenever i try to print the data type of each element in the column (like:

```
for i in data['Year]:
print(type(i))
```

the results I get is still all floats.

Anyone has any idea of why this wouldn't be working? Help would be very much appreciated it!

Comment: do you have sample data?

Comment: are you sure that expression in "if" statement is true? is data['Year'] actually float?

Comment: Put a print statement in the `if isinstance` block.  I don't think it's actually executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `data['Year']` is a `list` instead of `float` in your code. Try

```
data = {'Year': [1990.0, 1991, 2000.0]}

for idx, i in enumerate(data['Year']):
    if isinstance(i, float):
        data['Year'][idx]= int(i)

for i in data['Year']:
    print(type(i))
```